# 404 error using Telegraf webhook for a bot

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, webhooks, telegram-webhook, telegraf.js

I'm trying to make a Telegram bot working, and I'm using Telegraf.js. I've set up a webhook by adding a subdomain to my domain name with a default Apache VirtualHost.
It's basically working but for a reason I've got a 404 error from the Telegram's webhook API info (getWebhookInfo):

```json
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": {
    "url": "https://subdomain.domain.tld/telegraf/<chain-of-64-letters-and-numbers>",
    "has_custom_certificate": false,
    "pending_update_count": 12,
    "last_error_date": 1652692046,
    "last_error_message": "Wrong response from the webhook: 404 Not Found",
    "max_connections": 40,
    "ip_address": "XX.XX.XX.XX"
  }
}
```

I've noticed a suffix has been appended for a reason (I'm supplying only the subdomain URL without any path), it's probably from Telegraf.js but it seems to be causing the 404 error.

My code:

```js
const { Telegraf } = require("telegraf");
require("dotenv").config();

// Bot initialization
const token = process.env.API_KEY;
if (token === undefined) {
    throw new Error("Token not defined!");
}

const bot = new Telegraf(token/*, {
    telegram: {
        apiRoot: "http://127.0.0.1:" // I'm planning to use tdlib/telegram-bot-api later on
    }
}*/);

// Commands handling
bot.start(ctx => {
    console.info("ok!");
    ctx.reply("Hello from bot!");
});

bot.on("text", () => console.info("text received"));

bot.command("test", ctx => ctx.reply("Working!!"));

bot.command("quit", ctx => ctx.leaveChat());

// Bot launching
bot.launch({
    webhook: {
        domain: "https://subdomain.domain.tld",
        port: 3000 // I've seen 3000 is frequently used so let's use that
    }
}).then(
    resolve => console.info(`Bot '${bot.botInfo.username}' (${bot.botInfo.id}) started successfully (${resolve || "OK"})`),
    reject => console.info(`Bot '${bot.botInfo.username}' (${bot.botInfo.id}) failed to start: ${reject}`)
);

// Graceful stop handling
process.once("SIGINT", () => bot.stop("SIGINT"));
process.once("SIGTERM", () => bot.stop("SIGTERM"));
```

My VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName subdomain.domain.tld

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # Let's Encrypt
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld-0001/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld-0001/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the `ProxyPass` on my Apache `VirtualHost`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName subdomain.domain.tld

    # Missing part
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
    # End of missing part

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # Let's Encrypt
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld-0001/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld-0001/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Now it's working like a charm.